# Difficulties to get SSL certification in my website

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, ionos

How can I get the green locker sign or "secure connection" in my browser URL address?

1. Already  I have a SSL certification supplied by my hosting (Ionos).
2. Both my Wordpress address (URL) and site address (URL) starts with "https:/" instead of "http:/"
3. Also I redirect to the new https:/ URL whole traffic received in http:/ by 301 redirection at .htaccess
4. More over I have remove Wordpress cache using plugin "WP Super Cache"

What else I need to see the green locker?

Comment: Are you using a browser that uses a green padlock as the secure symbol? Most don't these days. Do you get an insecure warning? What does it say is the problem when you click on it?

Comment: Most of the time, with a webhost SSL certificate, If a subdomain as been added AFTER the SSL certification, you have to ask for a new one to be issued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in the right way:

1.- You need a SSL certification. Your hosting will supply, usually included in the hosting package.

2.- Either Wordpress or any other CMS you have to address visitors to the right site, maybe on the beginning you had an URL starting by http:/ so if you want to move to the new secure site you need to address properly to the new https:/.

3.- If your website is not new and you want to redirect to https:/ any visitor arriving http:/ you can add to your .thaccess file the right code to do:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>}
```

4.- Be aware that not only your site address should be move from http:/ to https:/ also whole your own links contained in the site should be move. The aim is: your site is secure if your links are also secure. You can use a more generic code to do it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

5.- Unfortunately, most probably this will not be enough. Be aware that e.g. all your images addressed to http:/...img now should be address to https:/. So you have to look for (ctrl + f) http:/ in the source code (right mouse click on the page you try to make secure at any browser --> "see source code"). Then edit the html file related to this page and simply substitue every http:/ by the https:/

6.- Only when you have make secure all links your site will be secure. Be brave and go ahead, succeed is at the end.

Sources:

https://www.hostinger.es/tutoriales/como-activar-ssl-y-https-en-wordpress/
https://www.hostinger.es/tutoriales/cache-wordpress#Como-borrar-la-cache-en-WordPress